# Using LISTEN in PSQL function and catch message

Tags: sql, postgresql, listen

I would like to build a function that would call the LISTEN command and return text from MESSAGE. I try the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test (in a_waiterror text)

RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
     EXECUTE format ('LISTEN %I', a_waiterror);

return 'message_text';
END
$$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

But how to catch an asynchronous message like this?:

```
Total query runtime: 35 msec
Received 1 line.

Received asynchronous "waiterror_aeaf6e0f_aecf_5bfe_9414_83951d92fb0f" notification from server process with PID 30703
    Data: {"message": "Customer information \" Banko Petr \ "loaded.", "Result": 0}
```

Is it possible to catch a returned message from LISTEN even if there is no error?